# image pathways for css

Tags: html, css

I cleaned up my files, as seen below by adding an images folder. Moving all imgs into /imgs/home. This has worked fine, except for background-images. They're being completely dismissed, I don't understand why because every other image works fine, is this a known bug?

```
old pathway -> "website/image1.jpg"
new pathway -> "website/imgs/home/image1.jpg"

How I grab an image -> works fine
<img src = "imgs/home/"image1.jpg">

how I grab a background-image -> doesn't work
background-image: url("imgs/home/image1.jpg");
```

keep in mind before I would do and it worked fine.

```
 background-image: url("image1.jpg");
```

Comment: Is your CSS in a different directory?

Comment: website/css ... but the css styles are being applied

Comment: Your url references either need to be static, or properly relative to the directory of the CSS file. Like @Christian Hain suggested, using a "../" before the relative url should fix this, or you can use a static URL, such as "site.com/imgs/home/image1.jpg".

Comment: Absolute path are easier to deal with

Answer (score 0):

Since your path is relative, you may need to up to the parent and back down to your `imgs` directory.

```
background-image: url("../imgs/home/image1.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you **homepage.html** file in the directory of **website**

Could you try it in this way, add a style in the HTML file body tag.

`<body style="background:url(imgs/home/imaga1.jpg)"></body>`

or  `<body background="imgs/home/image1.jpg">`

you also can edit it in your **CSS file**

`body {
    background-image: url("imgs/home/imaga1.jpg");
      }`